# Hibernate QuerySyntaxException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two classes called Batch and Position and I'm having this error

`Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree [from bean.Position p where :batch member of p.positionConstraint]`

when calling the method findByStudent. I'm also using JPA, if it helps. Thanks a lot

```
public  class  Position {  
@ElementCollection
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)  
@CollectionTable(name = "position_constraint")  
private  List<Batch> positionConstraint;  
}


public  class  Batch {
private  College college;

private  YearLevel yearLevel;

@Override
public  List<Position> findByStudent(StudentInformation student) {  
Batch batch = new  Batch(student.getCollege(), student.getYearLevel());  

Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(
"from Position p where :batch member of p.positionConstraint").setParameter("batch", batch);  
return query.getResultList();  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you have an error in your string. It should be:
`"from Position p where :batch member of p.positionConstraint"`

Comment: @Stephen C sorry, it still doesn't work. I updated the main question just in case.

Comment: @louieansonng can you also check that the collection is not null (and not empty, I saw some indications in the net, that this might be causing the problem).

Comment: @BorisStrandjev if this were the problem shouldn't it have a null pointer exception instead? I am sure that the collection is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works for me with combination of Hibernate 3.6.8.Final and database H2 1.3.160. Also with JPA equivalent query:

```
select from Position p where :batch member of p.positionConstraint
```

Depending about version of Hibernate you use, can be that you are are facing this bug: [HHH-5209](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5209), which is still open. Also [HHH-5173](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5713) provides some additional explanation.